# Why eslint throw an error with ?? condition?

Tags: javascript, eslint

this is my configuration of eslint :

```yaml
globals:
    require: true
    global: true
    $: true
env:
    browser: true
    es6: true
extends: 'eslint:recommended'
parserOptions:
    ecmaVersion: 2018
    sourceType: module
```

In my js I've got this line :

```js
let checkboxChecked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('previouslyChecked')) ?? {};
```

Eslint throw this error => `error  Parsing error: Unexpected token ?`
I don't want to use `// eslint-disable-line`but I don't understand why he does not know this `??`

Any idea ?

Comment: Your parser `ecmaVersion` is `2018`. This version does not have `??`.

Answer (score 1):

`ecmaVersion` must be `2020` or later to use `??`:

```yaml
parserOptions:
    ecmaVersion: 2020
    sourceType: module
```

See this [article](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/new-operators-in-ecmascript-2020-3dbb886b2fd9) for other new things in ES2020.